# How to send a file with telegram bot in python

Tags: python, telegram

I´m trying to send a file using the code below which results in the following error:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How can I fix this?

```
bot_token = ""
bot_chatId = ""

a = open('/home/scrapy/diff.csv', 'rb')
send_document = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token +'/sendDocument?'
data = {
  'chat_id': bot_chatId,
  'parse_mode':'HTML',
  'caption':'This is my file'
   }

r = requests.post(send_document, data=data, files=open('/home/scrapy/diff.csv','rb'),stream=True)
print(r.url)

return r.json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
r = requests.post(send_document, data=data, files={'document': a},stream=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`sendDocument`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument) method needs 2 required parameters: `chat_id`  and `document`,
you already provided the `chat_id`, to add the `document` field you should do :

```
bot_token = ""
bot_chatId = ""

a = open('/home/scrapy/diff.csv', 'rb')
send_document = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token +'/sendDocument?'
data = {
     'chat_id': bot_chatId,
     'parse_mode':'HTML',
     'caption':'This is my file'
}

r = requests.post(send_document, data=data, 
files={'document': open('/home/scrapy/diff.csv','rb')}, stream=True)
print(r.url)

return r.json()
```